# How to store credit amount safely in MongoDB for a custom online wallet system

Tags: mongodb, payment

I'm in the process of building an online credit system which takes my customers' real money and convert them to credits, which would be stored in the database. I thought of storing them as Number, which is plain and simple. But I worry that this is not safe if someone were to hack into the database as the hacker could just change the remaining credit number to whatever number he wants.

So I went for an aes encryption with a per-user salt for each user's remaining credit field. I wonder if this is necessary as encryption and decryption might slow down the overall server performance. Also, this prevents me from using `$gte` comparison when updating the value because the values are encrypted. This might cause racing condition under certain circumstances. Is it better if I just store it as it is?

Comment: Store both plain and encrypted value.

Comment: I agree with @Alex Blex

Answer (score 0):

it is best to use encrypt and decrypt the number to make it secure but it will definetly slow down the process but i read a doc which contain some security measures to prevent data from outsiders you should check out the doc [this is the link](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/how-to-avoid-a-malicious-attack-that-ransoms-your-data) this is an official doc of mongodb in which they define various security measures to prevent your data from hacker. i hope it will help you to protect you database

Comment: Good article: )